# Do you keep unspent commander skill points when transfered?

Tags: world-of-warships

My Tier V Omaha has a commander with 6 unspent skill points. I want to transfer him to my Tier VI Pensacola. Will the skill points stay when I transfer him?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they carry over, but you do have to retrain your commander for the XP he currently has.